# cannot start Ubuntu desktop from console

Tags: 12.04, command-line

I am trying to re-enter my ubuntu desktop 12.04 LTS after an upgrade that failed due to the computer going out of power during the upgrade. Since then, when I log in with my password, I get onto the console:

```
david@david-laptop:
```

If I type startx I get the line:

```
'X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting'
```

I tried:

```
sudo chown username:groupname .Xauthority
```

but that got me back to the initial command line.

How can I re-enter my desktop in this configuration? Thanks !

Comment: Recovering the files from the comptuer and installing 14.04 probably would be best solution... You could however try renistalling Unity etc with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common`.

Now select `Console Users Only`

[image]